# how many volts will it take to run a 12 volt motor

Tags: voltage

I am attempting to repair a lemax Halloween decoration for my wife. The power adapter says 9 v output but there are 2 motors inside the decoration that shows 12 v. Does this mean the adapter is rated too small to operate the motors?

Comment: The adaptor may be enough if the load on the motor(s) is not excessive.

Comment: The "9v" adapter may supply more than 9v for light loads, too

Answer (score 7):

A motor in itself can run at any voltage up to its rated voltage (and beyond provided a heat sink is added). The performance of the motor in terms of speed VS torque, and therefore the [speed;torque] operating point, will be decreased accordingly though. If the stall torque (maximum torque at 0 rpm) is smaller than or equal to the load torque (due to static friction first), the motor will not start at all and there will be no operating point.

[image]

Imagine your motor has a torque constant of 1 N.m/A, and a winding resistance of 10Ohms. Let the static friction of the load prevent any movement up to 0.5N.m. The motor will barely start turning when the motor torque goes past 0.5N.m, which requires a current of 0.5A. 0.5A flows through 10Ohms when 5V are applied.

Applying more than 5V will make the motor speed up. However, as it speeds up (unless it operates in vacuum) viscous friction will increase, requiring more and more torque. In addition, as it speeds up the effective voltage applied, and therefore the motor torque, will decrease due to a counteracting "back electromotive force" (which is a voltage, not a force) induced. The rotor rpm will stabilise when motor torque balances load torque. That's the operating point.

In a nutshell, there is nothing wrong with running a 12V motor on anything below 12V, but it will be weaker, and therefore slower, or even may fail to start depending on the load.

Your 12V motors are overkill, but 12V motors are very common, so they must have been included in the design for their cost effectiveness and used under conditions that are less demanding than what they've been built for.

Answer (score 3):

Driving motors is not a very precise art (unless you want it to be!). They can begin turning (With no load) way lower voltage than their "rated" or "designed" drive voltage.

A 6V motor may begin turning at 2V for example.

The issue is, as Andy Aka is hinting to in his comment, voltage relates to how much torque the motor can apply, which also ends up relating to velocity. The motors sound like they arent doing much, so 9V is obviously good enough to operate the motors at the required speed and torque.

Comment: I really appreciate everyone's input. I have very little electrical experience but need to increase my knowledge. I pulled one of the motors out and stripped the wires on the power plug and on the motor so I could test the motor without any other components being in the loop. The motor did not turn at all. I tried touching it to a A A battery and still nothing however when I check the motor with a multimeter I do see that it has current through the motor as well as the plug. Could the motor be seized yet still pass current? Do you think the motors are bad?

Comment: It probably means the "stall current" at 1.5V is too low to generate the torque required to start it. That's pretty normal. 3V (2*AA) will probably start it.

Comment: Ok. So I tried 2 A A batteries then 3 A A batteries and neither attempts turned the motor. Can I assume that the motor is bad? The motor says "synchronous motor A C 12 V 50/60 Hz 1.2-2w"

Comment: Is there any special module connected between the motor and the power pack? It may have a drive control which is not just direct DC power.

Comment: Yes. There is a .5 v d c coil between the power supply wires and the motors. I checked for current with a multimeter on the coils pins and got conductivity.

Comment: @JimSchwandt First of all, not sure what the 0.5VDC coil is for... Second, it sounds like you are not using the multimeter correctly. How exactly are you connecting/using the multimeter?

Comment: I used the ohms side at 1000k just to see if a current would pass through. This is what I did with the motors as well. Am I wrong?

Comment: @JimSchwandt can you describe how you connected the multimeter's probes, like in what order, to where, etc.?

Comment: Red and black wires are plugged into matching receptical on multimeter and the dial turned to ohms. I touched one lead to one wire each to read current on the multimeter. I did the sMe to confirm v d c on the incoming power cord. The cord says 19 v d c so I turned to meter to read d c and touched one lead to one wire each and got 19 v d c. So I know the incoming power supply is good. I went back to ohms on the meter and touch pins on the circuit board where the coil is soldered and got current.

Comment: so, multimeters cannot measure current like that. To measure current, the multimeter has to be sort of "inserted" between two circuit components. There are a lot of problems with that too, called the "burden voltage" which can affect the operation of things during measurement. Current has to see what flows through/into something, it cannot sense it in "parallel" which is how you normally measure voltage (one probe at the measurement node, parallel to ground or another reference point with the other probe). @JimSchwandt